# GENERAL QUESTION: Do you really need to use a wireframe in building a Salesforce Database?

Tags: community, developer-productivity

I would like to make a compelling arguement that you dont need to use a "Wireframe" in building a database to my boss as he insist of doing it.  My question to everyone, is it really important to wireframe a developing database?  I always thought wireframing is for web developemnt only.  Im building a database.  Can you just give me pros and cons of wireframing a SFDC database.  I think its really pointless.

Please advise

Comment: It's likely that your boss is asking for an ERD and not a wireframe. I would argue that developing an ERD is useful for database architecture.

Comment: Thats what Ive been telling them but since they are building a site the will pull data in salesforce (completely not my department) they want to see one.  And I think they just like graphical interface instead of a wired diagram.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed wireframing is meant for complete applications, not for only building a database.
However, an SFDC database is also an application (you can't build the database without generating the screens, API, etc).

I hardly ever do wireframing for SFDC applications, simply because it is just as much work as building the actual application in SFDC!

So if you want to do something like this, I'd suggest prototyping in a sandbox instead of wireframing in a totally different tool. That way the end users (and your boss) will immediately see both how the database is structured and how the application will look like and how it will work in SFDC.